# Visual Studio 2019, windows form application

Tags: keydown, disable

On my VS2019 disable in property Key Down.
[It is should be like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u9bC.png)
[But in my VS no option:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGVvQ.png).
How I can add KeyDown to continue work on my Windows form application?
Thank you!

I Tried to create manually event for keyDown:
private void pictureBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
```

...
but it does not work.

Comment: PictureBox is a simple control, all it does is display an image.  It cannot receive the focus.  Without focus, it won't have use for the keyboard either, that's why the events are hidden.  Why this matters is unguessable from the question.